# How to recover a deleted dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to recover a deleted BigQuery dataset with all the tables?

I understand that there is a recovery procedure for the tables, but what about the datasets?

Comment: DId you load it from google cloud storage or was it assembled over time through streaming?  If you loaded the data from google cloud storage into bigquery, and neglected to delete the cloud storage copy (each attracts storage fees)  perhaps you still have a copy in cloud storage.

Comment: Streaming, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

There is no recovery mechanism for datasets, which is why we make it difficult to delete datasets that have tables in them.

Comment: The current procedure I am seeing is literally two clicks through the Web UI. I would not call it difficult at all.

What I would consider a bit more difficult is, for example, to enforce typing a longer sequence of characters. Some other web services request exactly that to ensure the intention.

The other option would be a dataset recovery option.

Answer (score 0):

To recover a lost dataset, you have to schedule backups which can then be restored later in case of a failure. To make a backup use the bq extract command. An example:

```
bq extract \
  --destination_format=AVRO \
  --use_avro_logical_types \
  --compression=SNAPPY \
  "my-project:my-dataset.my-table" \
  "gs://my-bucket/extract.avro"
```

To restore a lost dataset use the following command:

```
bq load \
  --source_format=AVRO \
  "my-project:my-dataset.my-table" \
  "gs://bucket/extract.avro"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restore a dataset after it has been deleted [if you take action within the time travel window](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#restore-delete-datasets) for your org.